# Is this equivalent to bounded variation?

Tags: bounded-variation

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and bounded with smooth boundary.  For $f \in L^1(\Omega)$, define
$$ \|D_1 f\|_M(\Omega) =\inf\left\{\liminf_{k\to\infty}\int_\Omega |\nabla f_k|\,dx \mid f_k \to f \text{ in } L^1(\Omega),\ f_k \in \text{ Lip }(\Omega)\right\}. $$  Here $\text{Lip}(\Omega)$ is the set of Lipschitz functions on $\Omega$.  Note that by Rademacher's Theorem, for $f \in \text{Lip}(\Omega)$, $\nabla f$ exists Lebesgue-a.e.  My question is, is $\|D_1 f\|_M(\Omega)$ the same as $\int_\Omega |Df|$ in general?  I have a feeling the answer is ''no'', because if it is ''yes'', people would probably use this as the definition of bounded variation instead of the usual definition, which I find more complicated.

Comment: Is $\omega$ supposed to be a test function?

Comment: Oops, the $\omega$ doesn't belong there.  I removed it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is another way to introduce the BV norm, sometimes called Miranda's definition. People do use it, but it does not mean the distributional definition can be forgotten. It's not a bad thing to have two or more definition of the same class. For example, they might generalize in different ways when we move beyond Euclidean spaces. [This dissertation](http://etd.ohiolink.edu/view.cgi?acc_num=ucin1211551579) is relevant.

Comment: Thanks!  I think this is a record for the longest it's taken me to get a useful answer!  I have done a fair amount of reading about BV functions, and I'm surprised this definition is not more popular.  I kind of discovered it myself (without knowing for sure if it is equivalent to the usual definition).  I don't think Giusti's book even mentions it.  In my opinion, it is much simpler than the standard definition.